# Azure App Functions file system

Tags: function, azure

We are building an App function that requires access to the file system. I have read elsewhere that the storage is not dedicated to a particular app and is shared. Is there any way that the app would be shifted to a new storage location while running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Azure Function application has multiple file-system storage locations.

d:\local points to a non-shared local-to-the-VM storage.  It is temporary, as in when your function is deprovisioned from the VM, the storage goes away.  You have 500MB to store here.  So if we have scaled your function app to 5 instances, each of the five instances will run on its own VM and each will have its own d:\local storage of 500MB.

d:\home points to a shared storage folder which all your function application instances have access to.  As your function apps get scaled out or moved, the folder remains the same.  Of course implied by this is that for scale-reasons you may not want to have performance critical paths use it.

And of course you can access storage APIs yourself in your function.

Hope that helps.